What is this usage of 流しておいた
The character is a stunt. he's explaining to the protagonist the kind of moves he did aren't typically stunt moves, but parkour so he says:
「あれはパルクールって言います。この頃結構メジャーな感じで動画にもなって、勉強してるんです」
「海外の動画だとパルクール結構上がってますよ。流れて来たりしません？」
The protagonist adds
「あんまり、かもですね」
あまりどころか携帯電話やネット、ＳＮＳ自体に興味が薄く、だから緩く流しておいた。
I'm stumbled on what to make of 流しておいた here. I understand he's saying it they often pop up in oversea movies. Then protagonist comments he doesn't 流して "Much" but then his narration adds he generally has no interest in sns, etc.
What does 流して here mean? especially given he ておいた here

Do you have a source for this dialogue?

This 流しておいた means "I let it slide" or "I let the subject drop".

This 流す means to deliberately choose not to pursue the topic.
The subsidiary verb (-て)おく is used to add a sense of "then let it go" or "then leave it in that state".
The implied object of 流す is the topic (話題).
The use of the adverb 緩く ("gently; softly") here seems a little atypical, but it appears to emphasize that the protagonist did so naturally, without drawing attention or sounding impolite. We more commonly say 軽く流す or さらっと流す.


I see, but it's 流れて来たりしません？」 here then different?

@Kawase_K Yes, the two are different, and native speakers wouldn't even notice similar verbs are used.

This likely refers to social media in general. "ツイートが流れて来る" refers to the flow of posts when you scroll through Twitter, as used in this example from Youglish; he also includes other social media sites as well. This is very informal, but likely just means "have you seen the parkour online and such?"
Check the description under タイムライン here as well; the verb phrase is used.
ておく means something was done in preparation or for some purpose. The speaker is not into SNS and such, so it flowed to him "loosely," or not so much, so he would not have seen it beforehand while scrolling on social media.
